# How to disable smart quotes in Outlook 2016

Tags: ms-office, autocorrect

[Same question, different version](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/117219/how-do-i-disable-smart-quotes-apostrophes-in-mac-outlook-2011). Outlook 2016 doesn't have the Edit > Substitutions menu item, and it ignores the setting in System Preferences > Keyboard > Text > Use smart quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit > Preferences > AutoCorrect > AutoFormat > "Straight quotation marks" with “smart quotaton marks”

[image]